# Does pandas have a default fill value when constructing a dataframe of a specific dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dictionary `d`:

```
d = {'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, 'B': {'y': 1, 'z': 1}}
```

when I pass this to [pandas.DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, I know I'll have missing values for row x, column B and row z, column A.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

     A    B
x  1.0  NaN
y  1.0  1.0
z  NaN  1.0
```

I want to those `NaN` to be filled in with `0`.  Of course I know I can fill it in.

```
df.fillna(0)
```

But now they are all floats

```
     A    B
x  1.0  0.0
y  1.0  1.0
z  0.0  1.0
```

Yes! I could have forced them to integers

```
df.fillna(0).astype(int)

   A  B
x  1  0
y  1  1
z  0  1
```

Or! I could have constructed a series with a clever dictionary comprehension and unstacked with a fill_value parameter

```
pd.Series(
    {(i, j): v for j, d_ in d.items() for i, v in d_.items()}
).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

But all this would be a ton easier if there were a direct way to fill in missing with a default value from the start.  I'd expect something like

```
pd.DataFrame(d, dtype=int, fill_value=0)
```

I know that isn't available, but is there something else I've missed?

Comment: The dtype here is inferred due to missing values though, as you had to fill the missing values as a post-processing step you would need to cast to `int` to coerce the `dtype`

Comment: @EdChum Yes!  when I did `pd.DataFrame(d)` it had to infer.  However, if I specified the dtype in the constructor, it would be handy to be able to specify what to do with missing.

Comment: One possible solution is add missing keys  in `dict` and set val to `0` - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33910764/2901002).

Answer (score 12):

Since [pandas 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support) you can use the Int64 dtype:

```
import pandas as pd    
d = {'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, 'B': {'y': 1, 'z': 1}}    
pd.DataFrame(d, dtype='Int64').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
x   1   0
y   1   1
z   0   1
```

Be aware of the capital **I** in '**I**nt64'. If you write it with lower 'i', i.e. 'int64', you will get floats.

Comment: My favorite answer of the day :)! For everyone: `Int64` is an `integer` datatype, that can represent `NAN`s!

Comment: what if we don't know datatypes each time and want to do it for all int64, float64, object etc. ?  In my case it fails if we use int64 but there is no column with datatype int64