# Change pandas default fillna setting

Tags: pandas, default, fillna

I would like to change the default behavior of `pandas` to fill empty elements with something other that `float('nan')`, without modifying the source code. I can easily replace `NaN` *after* I've created a `DataFrame` using `DataFrame.fillna()`, but instead would like to change this behavior for all `DataFrames` before they are even instantiated.

In my application, I use a library that for some reason crashes if a `float('nan')` appears in `Python`, so my idea is to change the `pandas` default fill so that `float('nan')` never appears. Is there a way to change the default behaviour?

EDIT:

I tried `pd.set_option('mode.use_inf_as_na', True)` to no avail

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

Comment: [That's been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460685/does-pandas-have-a-default-fill-value-when-constructing-a-dataframe-of-a-specifi) and apparently no one had the answer ;} I'd guess pandas doesn't had a built-in option for that?

Comment: I edited the question with an attempt, but it did not work.

Comment: how are you building your dataframe? with `pd.DataFrame()` or `pd.read_csv()` or something else?

Comment: @MasonCaiby, I am building the datafame with `pd.DataFrame()`, the data comes from a Python list.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame()` does not have that functionality, but you can just replace the items in your list with a number, e.g. `my_list = [i if i != 'bad' else 0 for i in a]`

Comment: The problem is that as soon as NaN appears, the program crashes. Perhaps it would have been better for me to ask "how to change the `pd.concat()` behavior to avoid NaN.

Answer (score 2):

Missing data in `pandas` is represented by *NaN*. The above option, `pd.set_option('mode.use_inf_as_na', True)` simply tells `pandas` to recognise `inf` as a *NaN* in calculations.

As an example, after setting option `isna` will now include `inf`:

```
In [7]: pd.DataFrame([np.inf, 2, 3, np.inf]).isna()                                                                               
Out[7]: 
       0
0  False
1  False
2  False
3  False

In [8]: pd.set_option('mode.use_inf_as_na', True)                                                                                 

In [9]: pd.DataFrame([np.inf, 2, 3, np.inf]).isna()                                                                               
Out[9]: 
       0
0   True
1  False
2  False
3   True
```

Currently `pandas` does not have the above functionality, sorry not really a solution to your problem.

As the comment above says you are better off replacing the *NaN* values before initialising your `pd.DataFrame()`.

For example, setting `None` to zero.

```
list_from_source_code = [None, 2, 3, 4, None, 6, 7]
clean_list_from_source_code = [0 if i is None else i for i in list_from_source_code]

In [4]: pd.DataFrame(clean_list_from_source_code).head(3)                                                                         
Out[4]: 
   0
0  0
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Hopefully they add that capability in the future. Regardless, I should figure out why the API crashes...

Comment: Yeah that's strange as by definition `type(np.nan) == float` is true, I would take a look at the trace back might actually be something else just triggered by the `nan` occurrence